# Populating new variable using vlookup with multiple criteria in another variable

Tags: stata, lookup

1) A new variable should be created for each unique observation listed in variable `sku`, which contains repeated values.

2) These newly created variables should be assigned the value of own product's `price` at the store/week level, as long as observations' `sku` value is in the same subcategory (`subc`) as the variable itself. For example, in `eta2,3,` observations in line 3, 4, and 5 have the same value because they all belong to the same subcategory as sku #3. [`eta2,3` indicates sku 3, subc 2.]

3) `x` indicates that this is the original value for the product/subcategory that is currently being replicated.

4) If an observation doesn't belong to the same subcategory, it should reflect "0".

Orange is the given data. In green are the values from the steps 1, 2, and 3. White cells are step 4.

[image]

I am unable to offer a solution of my own, as searching for a 
way to generate a variable using existing observations hasn't given me results.

I also understand that it must be a combination of `forvalues`, `foreach`, and `levelsof` commands?

```
clear
input units price   sku week    store   subc
3   4.3 1   1   1   1
2   3   2   1   1   1
1   2.5 3   1   1   2
4   12  5   1   1   2
5   12  6   1   1   3
35  4.3 1   1   2   1
23  3   2   1   2   1
12  2.5 3   1   2   2
35  12  5   1   2   2
35  12  6   1   2   3   
3   20  1   2   1   1
2   30  2   2   1   1
4   40  3   2   2   2
1   50  4   2   2   2
9   10  5   2   2   2
2   90  6   2   2   3
end
```

***UPDATE***
Based on Nick Cox' feedback, this is the final code that gives the result I have been looking for:

```
clear
input units price   sku week    store   subc
35  4.3 1   1   1   1
23  3   2   1   1   1
12  2.5 3   1   1   2
10  1   4   1   1   2
35  12  5   1   1   2
35  12  6   1   1   3
35  5.3 1   2   1   1
23  4   2   2   1   1
12  3.5 3   2   1   2
10  2   4   2   1   2
35  13  5   2   1   2
35  13  6   2   1   3
end

egen joint = group(subc sku), label 

bysort store week : gen freq = _N
su freq, meanonly 
local jmax = r(max) 
drop freq

tostring subc sku, replace
gen new = subc + "_"+sku 


su joint, meanonly 
forval j = 1/`r(max)'{     
 local J = new[`j'] 
    gen eta`J' = . 
} 

sort  subc week store sku 
egen joint1 = group(subc week store), label 

gen long id = _n 
su joint1, meanonly  

quietly forval i = 1/`r(max)' { 
   su id if joint1 == `i', meanonly
   local jmin = r(min) 
   local jmax = r(max) 

   forval j = `jmin'/`jmax' {  
   local subc = subc[`j'] 
   local sku = sku[`j'] 
   replace eta`subc'_`sku' = price[`j'] in `jmin'/`jmax' 
   replace eta`subc'_`sku' = 0 in `j'/`j'  
   }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `rangestat` (SSC) offers a tool for looking at other values of a variable within subgroups, including the case where the present observation is strictly excluded. Searching Statalist archives will show hundreds of posts mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

I worry on your behalf that in a dataset of any size what you ask for would mean many, many extra variables. I wonder on your behalf whether you need all of them any way for whatever you want to do with them.

That aside, this seems to be what you want. Naturally your column headers in your spreadsheet view aren't legal variable names. Disclosure: despite being the original author of `levelsof` I wouldn't prefer its use here.

```
clear
input units price   sku week    store   subc
35  4.3 1   1   1   1
23  3   2   1   1   1
12  2.5 3   1   1   2
10  1   4   1   1   2
35  12  5   1   1   2
35  12  6   1   1   3
end

sort subc sku 
* subc identifiers guaranteed to be integers 1 up 
egen subc_id = group(subc), label 

* observation numbers in a variable  
gen long id = _n 

* how many subc? loop over the range 
su subc_id, meanonly 
forval i = 1/`r(max)' { 

   * which subc is this one? look it up using -summarize-
   * assuming that subc is numeric!    
   su subc if subc_id == `i', meanonly  
   local I = r(min) 

   * which observation numbers for this subc? 
   * given the prior sort, they are all contiguous 
   su id if subc_id == `i', meanonly 

   * for each observation in the subc, find out the sku and copy its price 
   * to all observations in that subc  
   forval j = `r(min)'/`r(max)' { 
       local J = sku[`j'] 
       gen eta_`I'_`J' = cond(subc_id == `i', price[`j'], 0) 
   }
}    

list subc eta*, sepby(subc)

     +------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | subc   eta_1_1   eta_1_2   eta_2_3   eta_2_4   eta_2_5   eta_3_6 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    1       4.3         3         0         0         0         0 |
  2. |    1       4.3         3         0         0         0         0 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------|
  3. |    2         0         0       2.5         1        12         0 |
  4. |    2         0         0       2.5         1        12         0 |
  5. |    2         0         0       2.5         1        12         0 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |    3         0         0         0         0         0        12 |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Notes:

N1. In your example, `subc` is numbered 1, 2, etc. My extra variable `subc_id` ensures that to be true even if in your real data the identifiers are not so clean.

N2. The expression

```
cond(subc_id == `i', price[`j'], 0)
```

could also be

```
(subc_id == `i') * price[`j']
```

N3. It seems possible that a different data structure would be much more efficient.

EDIT: Here is code and results for another data structure.

```
clear
input units price   sku week    store   subc
35  4.3 1   1   1   1
23  3   2   1   1   1
12  2.5 3   1   1   2
10  1   4   1   1   2
35  12  5   1   1   2
35  12  6   1   1   3
end

sort subc sku 
egen subc_id = group(subc), label 

bysort subc : gen freq = _N
su freq, meanonly 
local jmax = r(max) 
drop freq

forval j = 1/`jmax' { 
    gen eta`j' = . 
    gen which`j' = . 
} 

gen long id = _n 
su subc_id, meanonly  

quietly forval i = 1/`r(max)' { 
   su id if subc_id == `i', meanonly
   local jmin = r(min) 
   local jmax = r(max) 

   local k = 1 
   forval j = `jmin'/`jmax' { 
       replace which`k' = sku[`j'] in `jmin'/`jmax' 
       replace eta`k' = price[`j'] in `jmin'/`jmax' 
       local ++k 
   }
}    

   list subc sku *1 *2 *3 , sepby(subc)

     +------------------------------------------------------------+
     | subc   sku   eta1   which1   eta2   which2   eta3   which3 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    1     1    4.3        1      3        2      .        . |
  2. |    1     2    4.3        1      3        2      .        . |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  3. |    2     3    2.5        3      1        4     12        5 |
  4. |    2     4    2.5        3      1        4     12        5 |
  5. |    2     5    2.5        3      1        4     12        5 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |    3     6     12        6      .        .      .        . |
     +------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Dear Nick - I am going through your generous code right now. Is there a way for me to just calculate the number of potentially created variables? (Just the number)

Comment: For the first code, it's the same as the number of observations, is it not? In your spreadsheet you have 1,1 1,2 1,3 2,4 2,5 2,6 but it's the second subscript alone that suffices as a counter.

Comment: OK, I see that this code only identifies prices at subcategory/sku level. We need to make sure that the prices are populated at the `store/week' level for each subcategory/sku eta.  What should I fix in the code?

Comment: Yes, you did say store-week in your text: the data example has just a single week. Loop over `egen joint = group(subc week)` combinations.

Comment: Nick, I have  trouble replicating your suggestion.

Comment: So, give a data example, your code attempt and explain what is wrong. O

Comment: OK, i added the comment

Answer (score 1):

I am adding another answer that tackles combinations of `subc` and `week`. Previous discussion establishes that what you are trying to do would **add an extra variable for every observation**. This can't be a good idea! At best, you might just have many new variables, mostly zeros. At worst, you will run into Stata's limits.

Hence I won't support your endeavour to go further down the same road, but show how the second data structure I discuss in my previous answer can be produced. Indeed, you haven't indicated (a) why you want all these variables, which are just the existing data redistributed; (b) what your strategy is for dealing with them; (c) why `rangestat` (SSC) or some other program could not remove the need to create them in the first place.

```
clear
input units price   sku week    store   subc
35  4.3 1   1   1   1
23  3   2   1   1   1
12  2.5 3   1   1   2
10  1   4   1   1   2
35  12  5   1   1   2
35  12  6   1   1   3
35  5.3 1   2   1   1
23  4   2   2   1   1
12  3.5 3   2   1   2
10  2   4   2   1   2
35  13  5   2   1   2
35  13  6   2   1   3
end

sort subc week sku 
egen joint = group(subc week), label 

bysort joint : gen freq = _N
su freq, meanonly 
local jmax = r(max) 
drop freq

forval j = 1/`jmax' { 
    gen eta`j' = . 
    gen which`j' = . 
} 

gen long id = _n 
su joint, meanonly  

quietly forval i = 1/`r(max)' { 
   su id if joint == `i', meanonly
   local jmin = r(min) 
   local jmax = r(max) 

   local k = 1 
   forval j = `jmin'/`jmax' { 
       replace which`k' = sku[`j'] in `jmin'/`jmax' 
       replace eta`k' = price[`j'] in `jmin'/`jmax' 
       local ++k 
   }
}    

list subc week sku *1 *2 *3 , sepby(subc week)

     +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | subc   week   sku   eta1   which1   eta2   which2   eta3   which3 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    1      1     1    4.3        1      3        2      .        . |
  2. |    1      1     2    4.3        1      3        2      .        . |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
  3. |    1      2     1    5.3        1      4        2      .        . |
  4. |    1      2     2    5.3        1      4        2      .        . |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
  5. |    2      1     3    2.5        3      1        4     12        5 |
  6. |    2      1     4    2.5        3      1        4     12        5 |
  7. |    2      1     5    2.5        3      1        4     12        5 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
  8. |    2      2     3    3.5        3      2        4     13        5 |
  9. |    2      2     4    3.5        3      2        4     13        5 |
 10. |    2      2     5    3.5        3      2        4     13        5 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 11. |    3      1     6     12        6      .        .      .        . |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 12. |    3      2     6     13        6      .        .      .        . |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Nick, the data structure is needed to replicate a previously published work, Allenby (1989). In order to run a linear regression, this must be a data structure based on his method.

Comment: How can a data structure with as least as many predictors as observations be of any use for regression?

Comment: we are attempting to generate a kind of cross-price elasticity matrix, so the number of predictors, while large, is still many fewer than the number of observations. I discovered that the new code provides an incorrect output. I am attempting to draw the sample table in excel. Soon, will update the question.

Comment: Thank you again Nick. I just reloaded a visual representation of how the data should look like. Both of your codes (from before vs. today) to some extent do what I am looking for.

Comment: Hmm. In all candour, you seem to keep changing the question and you are being selective about replying to my questions and suggestions. That's all allowed, but at this point I have lost interest in the thread. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, sorry if you got this impression. It was never my intention. Which questions did I ignore? I reloaded the visual representation because the last time I skipped the diversity of week/store combination. But in the essence, that is what is important. The rest of the task stays the same.

Comment: I am not offended, just making a decision about what to do with my time. Any more help will need to be from others.

Comment: Nick - thank you for your help. I will try to tweak your existing codes to account for store/week combinations.

Comment: Oh, for the past couple of days, I am going over and over again through all your codes with my dissertation advisor. Although the first version accounted for distinct etas for each sku/subcategory but without store/week, the last version, we discovered today, mistakenly populates etas with prices from other products (i.e. accounts for week/stores but not for skus/subcategories, and thus merges several etas in one). The solutions, in some sense, are the inverse of each other. The combination of the two is the solution I have been looking for.

Comment: I am lost. Which variable indicates product?

Comment: In your first version, you do account for subcategory and sku (i.e. product) when building etas. This solution is an **ideal** solution if I were not to account for store/weeks level of analysis. The first solution just needs to be replicated over and over again in the manner of `bysort store week`.

Comment: In the second version, the code no longer provides an output that distinguishes between different `eta_I_J`. There is only `eta_J`.

Comment: It's the job of `which_j` to hold `I`.

Comment: Dear @Nick Cox - thank you again for the codes. After days of struggle and occasional swearing, we have been able to get the right code by using a combination of your codes. I am updating the post with the final code in order for you to see what I was looking for. Thank you again. Without your guidance, there is no chance it would be possible at all.

Comment: Thanks for the closure. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
clear
input units price   sku week    store   subc
35  4.3 1   1   1   1
23  3   2   1   1   1
12  2.5 3   1   1   2
10  1   4   1   1   2
35  12  5   1   1   2
35  12  6   1   1   3
35  5.3 1   2   1   1
23  4   2   2   1   1
12  3.5 3   2   1   2
10  2   4   2   1   2
35  13  5   2   1   2
35  13  6   2   1   3
end

egen joint = group(subc sku), label 

bysort store week : gen freq = _N
su freq, meanonly 
local jmax = r(max) 
drop freq

tostring subc sku, replace
gen new = subc + "_"+sku 


su joint, meanonly 
forval j = 1/`r(max)'{     
 local J = new[`j'] 
    gen eta`J' = . 
} 

sort  subc week store sku 
egen joint1 = group(subc week store), label 

gen long id = _n 
su joint1, meanonly  

quietly forval i = 1/`r(max)' { 
   su id if joint1 == `i', meanonly
   local jmin = r(min) 
   local jmax = r(max) 

   forval j = `jmin'/`jmax' {  
   local subc = subc[`j'] 
   local sku = sku[`j'] 
   replace eta`subc'_`sku' = price[`j'] in `jmin'/`jmax' 
   replace eta`subc'_`sku' = 0 in `j'/`j'  
   }
}    

 list subc sku store week eta*, sepby(subc)


   +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | store   week   subc   sku   eta1_1   eta1_2   eta2_3   eta2_4   eta2_5   eta3_6 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     1      1      1     2      4.3        0        .        .        .        . |
  2. |     1      1      1     1        0        3        .        .        .        . |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  3. |     1      1      2     4        .        .      2.5        0       12        . |
  4. |     1      1      2     3        .        .        0        1       12        . |
  5. |     1      1      2     5        .        .      2.5        1        0        . |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |     1      1      3     6        .        .        .        .        .        0 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  7. |     1      2      1     2      5.3        0        .        .        .        . |
  8. |     1      2      1     1        0        4        .        .        .        . |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  9. |     1      2      2     3        .        .        0        2       13        . |
 10. |     1      2      2     5        .        .      3.5        2        0        . |
 11. |     1      2      2     4        .        .      3.5        0       13        . |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 12. |     1      2      3     6        .        .        .        .        .        0 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```