# Can egen group() produce actual values instead of 1, 2, 3,.....?

Tags: stata

In reference to https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-group-identifiers/:

> To create a new variable newid from the existing variable oldid,
>   whether oldid is string or numeric, type
>
> ```
>     . egen newid = group(oldid)
> ```
>
> The new variable newid will contain 1 for the first value of oldid, 2 for the second value, and so
>   on.

Can the `group()` command generate the actual values of the grouped variables instead of 1, 2, 3....? For example, in the following data set,

```
clear
input units price   sku week    store   subc
35  4.3 1   1   1   1
23  3   2   1   1   1
12  2.5 3   1   1   2
10  1   4   1   1   2
35  12  5   1   1   2
35  12  6   1   1   3
35  5.3 1   2   1   1
23  4   2   2   1   1
12  3.5 3   2   1   2
10  2   4   2   1   2
35  13  5   2   1   2
35  13  6   2   1   3
end
```

how do we modify command `egen long joint = group(subc sku)` such that `joint`'s actual values are:

```
clear
input units price   sku week    store   subc joint
35  4.3 1   1   1   1 1_1
23  3   2   1   1   1 1_2
12  2.5 3   1   1   2 2_3
10  1   4   1   1   2 2_4
35  12  5   1   1   2 2_5
35  12  6   1   1   3
35  5.3 1   2   1   1
23  4   2   2   1   1
12  3.5 3   2   1   2
10  2   4   2   1   2
35  13  5   2   1   2
35  13  6   2   1   3
end
```

Or in general terms, how to make sure that the result of the `group()` command is not modified by Stata?

Concatenation of the variables `subc` and `sku` is not an option, as it doesn't give me the needed results  in a `forval` loop.

Answer (score 1):

`group()` is an `egen` function, not a command.

Concatenation gives you exactly what you specify. What's wrong with this?

```
clear
input units price   sku week    store   subc
35  4.3 1   1   1   1
23  3   2   1   1   1
12  2.5 3   1   1   2
10  1   4   1   1   2
35  12  5   1   1   2
35  12  6   1   1   3
35  5.3 1   2   1   1
23  4   2   2   1   1
12  3.5 3   2   1   2
10  2   4   2   1   2
35  13  5   2   1   2
35  13  6   2   1   3
end

egen joint = concat(subc sku), p(_) 

list , sepby(subc)

     +---------------------------------------------------+
     | units   price   sku   week   store   subc   joint |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    35     4.3     1      1       1      1     1_1 |
  2. |    23       3     2      1       1      1     1_2 |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  3. |    12     2.5     3      1       1      2     2_3 |
  4. |    10       1     4      1       1      2     2_4 |
  5. |    35      12     5      1       1      2     2_5 |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  6. |    35      12     6      1       1      3     3_6 |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  7. |    35     5.3     1      2       1      1     1_1 |
  8. |    23       4     2      2       1      1     1_2 |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  9. |    12     3.5     3      2       1      2     2_3 |
 10. |    10       2     4      2       1      2     2_4 |
 11. |    35      13     5      2       1      2     2_5 |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
 12. |    35      13     6      2       1      3     3_6 |
     +---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This post is in reference to the previous post I had on loops. On a sample data set, the forval code works well. But when I apply it to the actual data set with 187K obs., it gives me the following error: `(187,177 missing values generated) [repeated 67 times];  variable eta2_598 already defined`. I figured out that the problem is with the `group` command.

Comment: In other words, this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48869124/1179111 doesn't work on large data sets, but it works on a sample data set. And I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: Sorry, but these comments don't help. You're asserting, not showing, that there is a problem using the `group()` function. How does `eta2_598` figure in any command that you're using?  That has no bearing on the question here.